# How to easily pull diffs between working dir and remote, skipping local repo?

Tags: git

I am looking for a way to show the deltas between my local working directory and the remote, i.e. what other people have pushed + what I have changed since the last time I pulled.  In that comparison, the local repository is not of concern to me, so I am not looking to `pull` and then `status`.  I am looking more for something like a status of the working directory directly against the remote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you run [`git fetch`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-fetch.html), you'll get all of the updates from the remote without any modifications to your local branches.  You can then do `git diff remote/whatever` to get a diff against the current state of the `whatever` branch on `remote`.

In case it's useful - you can see all of the remote branches your repository knows about by doing `git branch -a` or `git branch -r`.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that this does not diff "the working directory directly against the remote" as the OP asked. The changes from the remote are fetched into the local history, more precisely into the "remote-tracking branches". With Git, `diff`s can only happen on local data, and never "directly" on/against a remote.

Comment: +1 @NevikRehnel.  That's absolutely true; even remote branches are local in git.  If that makes sense...

Comment: that's why I put "remote-tracking" in quotes; the naming is a bit unfortunate, even if it does make some sense (only the emphasis is "remote-*tracking*") -- I think the Git devs are discussing renaming them to make it a bit clearer, but that name is around in a lot of documents already. Anywho, the important thing about Git is `--everything-is-local` ;)

Comment: Remote tracking means something else though; a (real) local branch that will update from a specific remote branch when doing `git pull`.

Comment: well, there's no proper consensus about the three variants (remote branch, remote-tracking branch, tracking branch), as our own discussion shows. I've never found any definition of any of the terms. While the [Pro Git book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches) calls them "remote branches", I and several people I know usually say "remote-tracking branches" when it's about things in `refs/remotes/*`, and "tracking" for a local branch tracking an upstream one -- but we digress :)